# Rearrange Data in Python using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I received data in the following format:

```
Date ,20100423
Open ,1028.75
High ,1029.5
Low ,1026
Close ,1026
S1 ,1030.62082869339
R1 ,1033.6233971724
S2 ,1026.87917130661
R2 ,1023.8766028276
Date ,20100426
Open ,1037.75
High ,1040.5
Low ,1037
Close ,1038.75
S1 ,1043.86350963032
R1 ,1040.79138126515
S2 ,1031.63649036968
R2 ,1034.70861873485
```

Need to re-arrange in following format:

```
Date    Open    High    Low     Close   S1  R1  S2  R2
xx      xx      xx      xx      xx      xx  xx  xx  xx
xx      xx      xx      xx      xx      xx  xx  xx  xx
```

How can I do this in Python / Pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way.

**Setup**

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

mystr = StringIO("""Date ,20100423
Open ,1028.75
High ,1029.5
Low ,1026
Close ,1026
S1 ,1030.62082869339
R1 ,1033.6233971724
S2 ,1026.87917130661
R2 ,1023.8766028276
Date ,20100426
Open ,1037.75
High ,1040.5
Low ,1037
Close ,1038.75
S1 ,1043.86350963032
R1 ,1040.79138126515
S2 ,1031.63649036968
R2 ,1034.70861873485""")
```

**Read file and restructure dataframe**

```
# read csv file with flexible separator
df = pd.read_csv(mystr, sep='\s*,\s*', engine='python',
                 header=None, names=['col', 'value'])

# create dataframe through iterating rows in chunks
res = pd.DataFrame([df.iloc[i*9:(i+1)*9, 1].tolist() for i in range(int(len(df.index)/9))],
                   columns=df.iloc[:9, 0].values)

# convert date column to datetime
res['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(res['Date'], format='%Y%m%d').dt.normalize()

print(res)

#         Date     Open    High     Low    Close           S1           R1  \
# 0 2010-04-23  1028.75  1029.5  1026.0  1026.00  1030.620829  1033.623397   
# 1 2010-04-26  1037.75  1040.5  1037.0  1038.75  1043.863510  1040.791381   

#             S2           R2  
# 0  1026.879171  1023.876603  
# 1  1031.636490  1034.708619
```